# Close the application

Tags: java

I want to close the application when I press Close icon which is X at the right top corner.. but when I press that icon, the application closes but in netbeans it's also showing that the current program is running. I want to close that all. I also check in properties window, it's EXIT_ON_CLOSE.

Comment: Please have a look at this thread [Quitting an application - is that frowned upon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon)

Comment: You may add a exit hook and do System.exit(0); there to be sure..